# DTAttributedTextContentView inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, dtcoretext

I'm targeting iOS7 and need to put a `DTAttributedTextContentView` inside a table cell.  I can't use a `DTAttributedTextCell` because I also need to place some `UILabel`s in the same cell, adjust it's indentation, and have other control.

I can't find any explicit sample code to do this, but I can see from SO questions that it's been done before.  Do I hook something up in Interface Builder in a prototype cell?  Do I create the `DTAttributedTextContentView` programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it with Storyboards is to create a prototype cell with UILabels (and whatever other elements you want) and a UIView, and set the UIView's class to `DTAttributedTextContentView`.  Grab an IBOutlet reference to this DTAttributedTextContentView in a custom UITableViewCell class, and you can now set its attributed string property in your table view controller.